# How to scrape a somewhat odd URL with Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, scrape

So basically I want to use Scrapy.org in order to scrape a forum. The problem I encounter is that the link to every thread are somewhat along this line http://mywebsite.com/forum/My-Thread-Name-t213.html 
Now, if I try to enter just http://mywebsite.com/forum/t213.html it doesn't work, it doesn't show the topic with that ID so I don't really know how I could generate the thread name and the id of each topic in order to be able to scrape it.
I would really appreciate some help with this one, thanks in advance !

Comment: Are the thread ids in a range of some kind eg: t001 to t300?

Comment: Also, could you give a concrete example of a thread URL please?

Comment: An actual url would be http://freakz.ro/forum/Spam-Akyzor-Dkill-t251680.html . The thread ids are in a range they go from 0 to x onward, but some of them should be deleted so there should be ids that return an error page, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of an actual URL to test, I cannot be absolutely sure that this is going to work. Essentially you need to use a regular expression in a `CrawlSpider` rule that starts with your base URL and matches that plus any string followed by `-t`, plus any number and then finally `.html`.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor

class ThreadSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "mywebsite"
    allowed_domains = ["mywebsite.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://mywebsite.com/forum"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(allow = ('/[^/]+-t\d+\.html')), follow=True,
        callback='parse_item'),]

    def parse_item(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        print "We're scraping %s" % response.url
        # do something with the hxs object
```

Comment: Looking again at it I found that posts can be accesed following this link http://freakz.ro/forum/view-post-3382479.html, but again, there are deleted posts. The number goes from 0 o inf so yea, it's a range. I think it's better to use this, but then the same page could be scraped 15 times (#posts/page).